# invalid main GPT header after a memory swap

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, uefi, gparted, gdisk

I'm trying to safely move space from Windows 7/8/10 to Ubuntu (GPT + UEFI Mode) with [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1QjQ4q5kcVs) tutorial.

I tried to edit `/etc/fstab` to tell it about the new swap and check if there were any changes in the UUIDs of any partitions in order to edit them if there were any. But when I launched the text-mode partitioning tools for Linux gparted it told me that the older Master Boot Record was valid

```
root@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu# gdisk -l /dev/sda
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.1

Caution: invalid main GPT header, but valid backup; regenerating main header
from backup!

Caution! After loading partitions, the CRC doesn't check out!
Warning! Main partition table CRC mismatch! Loaded backup partition table
instead of main partition table!

Warning! One or more CRCs don't match. You should repair the disk!

Partition table scan:
  MBR: MBR only
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: damaged

Found valid MBR and corrupt GPT. Which do you want to use? (Using the
GPT MAY permit recovery of GPT data.)
 1 - MBR
 2 - GPT
 3 - Create blank GPT

Your answer: 2
Disk /dev/sda: 1953525168 sectors, 931.5 GiB
Logical sector size: 512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): 6FAF53FA-01E2-4754-A71C-9AF3A67E5F84
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 1953525134
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 1953525101 sectors (931.5 GiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
root@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu#
```

Yet I had a quite different system :

[image]

And it should have been more or less like this :

[image]

Comment: You have Windows installed in BIOS boot mode which requires MBR. If you convert drive to gpt, then you destroy Windows.  Your video is for a Windows in UEFI boot mode which is on a gpt partitioned drive. If you want UEFI with gpt, you will have to reinstall Windows in UEFI boot mode which only works on gpt drives.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn898504%28v=vs.85%29.aspx & 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn898510%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#RecommendedPartitionConfigurations

Comment: @oldfred Ha okay ! No, I just want to increase the Ubuntu size whatever maybe the Windows boot mod. Should I select `1 - MBR`  then ?

Comment: Use Windows to shrink NTFS partition(s). but it looks like you have to move multiple partitions as you have to move left and expand right. And move can be very slow. And interruption usually destroys partition as half of data is moved & half not or totally corrupted. So be sure to have good backups. I often find it easier to reinstall and restore from backups. Also confirms backups are valid. But most of my earlier restoreswere to a totally new partition, so I have old partition to fall back on for anything I missed.